# Syntax Error: Adding div class to php variable that will be outputted

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a variable in my .php file that will contain a simple  class from CSS.  However the style is not showing up in my output.

CSS

```
#cost_class {
  color:#427120;
}
```

PHP

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($x)){
$id = $r["id"]; //ID OF CONTENT
$content = $r["content"]; //CONTENT ITSELF
$cost = $r["Cost"]; // COST
$address = $r["address"]; // ADDRESS

$m .= '<div>'.$content.'<br><br>';

include "variables.php"; //FILE WITH THE PERCENTAGES, BUTTON IMAGE URLS, AND WHETHER USER HAS RATED

$m .= '<div class = "cost_class">' .$cost. " " .$address. '</div><br></div>';
}

echo $m;
```

I know this is a syntax issue that is preventing the CSS from being displayed.

Comment: add your error in question

Answer (score 1):

change your css

```
.cost_class {
  color:#427120;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is asking for an element with *id* `cost_class`. For a *class*, it should be:

```
.cost_class {
  color:#427120;
}
```

A period signifies classes in CSS; a hash IDs.